# Localization of Bundle Display Name fails in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, localization, xcode4, bundle

I have an app that is localized in two languages. I'm trying to change the bundle display name according to the selected localization.
In many articles on the Internet, this is done localizing the info plist file.

I'm using XCode 4 and it automatically creates a MyProject-Info.plist file containing the bundle display name.
As soon as I try to localize it (even having only the first language added) I cannot build the app anymore, cause the Identifier field in the "Summary -> iOS Application Target" section in the project properties becomes blank (and I cannot edit it).

What happens in the file structure of the project is that the original MyProject-Info.plist files is moved to the en.lproj folder, as well as duplicated into the other *.lproj folders I have (one for each supported language).

Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.select "InfoPlist.strings" file 
2.Open “File Inspector"
3.add your localization language at Localization Section.
4.Open "InfoPlist.strings(English)" file, add CFBundleDisplayName = "Yours English Application Display Name";
5.Open "InfoPlist.strings(your local language)" file, add CFBundleDisplayName = "Yours Local Application Display Name";

Comment: I've done this for english and french. The french works all the time. But the english doesn't usually work. Sometimes it works in the simulator, but it doesn't work on the device. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the risk of being redundant, let me just clarify (as I've tested this right now) that the trick is to translate the InfoPlist.strings and *never* the MyProject-Info.plist.